# performing sortable using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a situation where i need to achieve this, in a table having n rows. if i click on a row in a table and then click on another row. the content in row of first click should go to content  in row of second click and then each row should be shifted by on step backward or forward. this can be taken equivalent to JQUERY sortable.

Example:

```
  |1|2|3|4| if i click on 1 and 4 then it should be |2|3|4|1|
```

how to record two clicks, and the contents of my rows are div elements containing many input elements. I thought of this idea and is this a good way to achieve sortable or is there a still better way, i want to do it using java script.

thanks in advance.

Comment: why was i down voted ? at least the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my script fucntion goes like this. I really should have thought for a little longer. i used flags here, i got two questions more, can i do that with out flags?, is there a better way?

```
<script>
var flag=0;
var id1;
var id2;
function Myfunction(id)
{
if(flag==0)
{
    id1=id;
    flag=1;
}
else
{
    id2=id; 
    var x=document.getElementById(id1).innerHTML;   
    var num1=parseInt(id1); 
    var num2=parseInt(id2);
    for(var i=num1;i<num2;i++)
    {
        var j=i.toString();
        var k=(i+1).toString();
        document.getElementById(j).innerHTML=document.getElementById(k).innerHTML;
    }
    document.getElementById(id2).innerHTML=x;
    flag=0; 
}   
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I made up a little http://jsfiddle.net/zxKeg/. Works with jQuery only, no additional plugins needed. Hope this will help you!

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $table = $('table');
    var $toCopy = null;
    $table.on('click', 'tr', function() {
        if($toCopy === null || $toCopy[0] == this) {
            $toCopy = $(this);
        }
        else {
            $toCopy.remove();
            $(this).after($toCopy);
            $toCopy = null;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: really appreciate it ! i don't know even basic syntax of JQUERY. so i cannot accept it. i upvoted for your effort.

Comment: Maybe i can help you integrate it. `var $table = $('table');` 'table' is a css-like selecor here, so just insert a selector matching your table (like #tableid or .tableclass)